# How to be notified when thread goes down?

Tags: java, multithreading

In java, I have ExecutorService that runs with while true, and Throwable catch clouse. I find out that from time to time the thread goes down. That means the system stop function.
So my question is, first of all, how can I catch the "thread killed" event (in order to send me email on such case)?
Also, how can this thread goes down?

the code is:

```
ExecutorService changesTrackerThread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
changesTrackerThread.submit(queueUpdater());        

private Runnable queueUpdater() {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {                                       
                    // do some code, then sleep
                    Thread.sleep(2000L);
                } catch (Throwable t)
                {
                    _log.error("something bad happened, but the loop should keep running", t);
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *goes down*. Does the thread terminate abruptly? And if so, is it due to an `Exception`? "*That means the system stop function*" I'm not sure what this means

Comment: You are using the Executor Service inappropriately. You should *schedule a repeated task* to it instead of `while (true)` with `Thread.sleep()`. BTW the only way for your thread to "go down" is when the `_log.error()` statement fails with an exception.

Comment: Does anything show up in your logs? Also, I think I understand your motivation, but catching Throwable is a bad practice.

Comment: @VinceEmigh goes down = terminated. i don't see it in a thread dump. The system not function means that its extreamly critical case, that I should know about when it happens. I don't know why it happened, from the code I can't see any case, including exception, that can kill the thread.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik  I am not sure how bad it is. But maybe you right - the code would be better if I will use repeaded task. Regarding the exception - I agree with you. but the log line cannot raise any exception. Nevertheless, after a while I can't see the thread in the thread dump.

Comment: @DavidConrad I didn't see anything in the log, but maybe they rolled out. I heard the theory that says not to catch throwable, but I extreamly disagree with it. My case is an example where throwable is more suitable - the "show must go on" no matter what happens inside: reflection errors, loading modules errors, etc. if there are some exception errors - maybe I should catch them specifically and re-throw them (e.g. OOM).

Comment: If you use a scheduled executor, your task would be run again, even if the previous iteration died with an exception. Otherwise, you could have a `finally` block that sets a flag for another, "watcher" thread to start a fresh copy of your thread. Either way, no need to catch `Throwable`; but a scheduled executor is the way to go.

Comment: The log statement most certainly *can* throw an exception, and that is precisely the only way for that thread to die.

Comment: @DavidConrad If you check out `ThreadPoolExecutor.Worker`, you'll see that it catches `Throwable` as well.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, and *immediately*, *unconditionally* rethrows it.

Comment: @DavidConrad Exactly. But that makes no difference regarding the damage such a `Throwable` may have caused to the runtime. In most cases it is irrelevant if the thread where a serious exception happened dies because the damage affects *all* threads.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik But even if it were not caught and rethrown, it would at most have only killed the thread it was being thrown on. And if there are other problems to the runtime (OOME), then Errors will be thrown on the other threads soon enough. I guess what your suggesting is to catch and note an Error, and shut down the JVM but have a watcher that would fire up a fresh one, instead of firing up a fresh thread? If so, that's a good idea and you should write it up as an answer.

Comment: @DavidConrad An OOME, just like an SOE, may break the invariants of any object, such as those used internaly by the JDK. There is no guarantee that the incurred damage will result in any further errors; it may result in incorrect behavior of those objects. However, real-life experience shows that shutting down the whole JVM due to any OOME/SOE would be a case of paranoid overreaction because 1) these errors are not that rare and 2) the theoretically possible global damage is very rare. The result would be avoidable downtime.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Okay, so don't keep running, and don't shut down. Either we're completely talking past each other, or I don't understand what you're getting at. In either case, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @DavidConrad I see how it may have become non-obvious, but this is the key point of all my comments: handling a Throwable (and letting the thread go on) is not a bad practice, unless it happens in a mission-critical application, where we want to guarantee 100% reliability. Not even *catching* a Throwable is a very bad practice because then you just let the thread die with no idea about the cause, and allow all other threads to proceed as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 3):

Well first of all, why are you using a while loop here!?

You should use a [scheduled executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
ExecutorService changesTrackerThread = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()();
changesTrackerThread.scheduleAtFixedRate(new queueUpdater(), 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        

private Runnable queueUpdater() {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                try
                {                                       
                    // do some code

                } catch (Throwable t)
                {
                    _log.error("something bad happened", t);
                }

        }
    };
```

I do not know why your thread dies, show us the full code.

But this way even if the thread dies the Excecutor will rerun it after the given period(2 seconds in this example.

Comment: If a thread in the pool dies, then the task which it was executing will be canceled.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you could replace your `while (true)` and `sleep()` loop with a `ScheduledExecutorService`. Scheduling a repeating task on such a service will return a `ScheduledFuture` which you can use to check the status of this task or to cancel it if you have a need for that. This will enable you to remove the try/catch block from the code.

Start the service like this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService svc = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

I would use `newScheduledThreadPool()` instead of `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` since the former will restart threads if necessary.

Then, schedule the work like this:

```
void doSomeCode() {
    // do some code
}

ScheduledFuture<?> sf = svc.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::doSomeCode, 0L, 2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

(Or if you wish you can inline `doSomeCode()` as a lambda or an anonymous inner class.)

Now what happens if the task fails with an exception? The `ScheduledFuture` object returned allows you to check status in a variety of ways. If you have a thread that you can dedicate to waiting for failures, you can have it call `sf.get()` which will throw an `ExecutionException` that wraps the exception that caused the task to fail. Otherwise, it blocks indefinitely. `ScheduledFuture.get()` is a bit weird in that unlike an ordinary `Future.get()` call, it never returns a value; it always throws an exception.

When/if the task fails, the caller of `sf.get()` can log the exception and resubmit the task, or whatever. If you don't want to block a thread indefinitely, you can poll for failure using `sf.isDone()` or `sf.get(0L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`. Note that both overloads of `sf.get()` communicate **all** of their return information via the type of a thrown exception, which may make them somewhat inconvenient to use.

You *could* put exception handling within the task itself, catching `Throwable` and continuing no matter what, and this will probably work. It does bake the logging/restart/resubmission policy into the task itself, which may be unpleasant. Using `ScheduledFuture` lets you separate these policies from the actual work performed by the task.